Ideas on how to separate encrypt keys in jpa attribute converter?
I am currently using jpa attribute converter to encrypt some of the db fields.  However, I have a requirement to separate the encrypt keys based on the other field on the entity.
for example, I would like to use key 123456 to encrypt the field name if org field is external, and use key qwert to encrypt field name if org field is internal.
JPA attribute does not have access to the entity's other field, so I have to find workarounds.
So is it possible to do this?
Thanks

Provide one solution for your scenario , one way to do this is by handling the encryption logic within itself ,or callback listener  method to apply encryption key before persisted or updated;
@Entity
@EntityListeners(MyEntityListener.class)
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String org; // "external" or "internal"

    private String name; // The name that will be encrypted in the DB

    // getters and setters
}

public class MyEntityListener {

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void encryptName(MyEntity entity) {
        String key = getKeyBasedOnOrg(entity.getOrg());
        entity.setName(EncryptionUtil.encrypt(entity.getName(), key));
    }

    @PostLoad
    public void decryptName(MyEntity entity) {
        String key = getKeyBasedOnOrg(entity.getOrg());
        entity.setName(EncryptionUtil.decrypt(entity.getName(), key));
    }

    private String getKeyBasedOnOrg(String org) {
        if ("external".equals(org)) {
            return "123456";
        } else if ("internal".equals(org)) {
            return "qwert";
        }
        return "defaultKey";
    }
}




Thanks!  Exactly what I was looking for!!!

BTW I don't think I can handle this in the encryption / decryption logic, because the enc/dec function only has access to the field value of name, it does not have access to org's value.

not very clear the enc/dec function only has access to the field value of name, it does not have access to org's value ,  so why org field so  special?, both them  just field in entity , if you can get the one , so do same in another one

I was using attributerconverter, the interface takes current attribute value, no other inputs.
